# Rails Query All Students Inside School

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm trying to make a database app for a school as practice. So here's the ERD that I constructed:

[image]

What I want to have is a list of students under a school. I know how to retrieve the teachers under a school and the students under the teacher it's basically just `school.teachers` and `teacher.students` but I don't know how to get what school -> students.

Comment: This might look unrelated to the question. Why does the `Student` table have a `TeacherId` column? A student most probably will have more than a single teacher right? `Teacher` and `Student` models should have a many-many association.

Comment: @Soundwave98 - you should accept the answer which ever sounds good for your req.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a *has many through* relation:

```rb
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students
end
```

```rb
class School < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teachers
  has_many :students, through: :teachers
end
```

And then just do

```
school = School.find(some_id)
students = school.students
```

Some notes:

Foreign keys in Rails are usually of the format `something_id`, so instead of `TeacherId` you would use `teacher_id`. Primary keys are usually just called `id`. Of course you can call them whatever you want, things just require less configuration if you go with the defaults.

Unless this is just to play around with Rails I'd probably change the relation between teacher and students to a many to many. In this case you'd need to `distinct` the students:

```rb
has_many :students, -> { distinct }, through: :teachers
```

UPDATE:

**Many To Many**

Yes, you are right. To have a many to many relation you will need a "join table". This is not mandated by Rails though, but the way relational DBs work. Perhaps it's best if you start a new question if you need help with goign that route.

**through**

`:through` is an option you can pass to `has_many`. It is described here
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association (altough they use a "has and belongs to many" association in the example)

In your example I think of it like: "Hey school, please give me all students that you can reach via the teachers"

And ActiveRecord will create a query similiar to this:

```
school = School.first
school.students.to_sql
 => "SELECT \"students\".* FROM \"students\" INNER JOIN \"teachers\" ON \"students\".\"teacher_id\" = \"teachers\".\"id\" WHERE \"teachers\".\"school_id\" = 1"
```

(where `1` is the ID of the school you called the `students` method on).

If you do the query as suggested by @TTD then it will most likely result in something like this:

```
school = School.first
Student.where(teacher: Teacher.where(school: s)).to_sql

 => "SELECT \"students\".* FROM \"students\" WHERE \"students\".\"teacher_id\" IN (SELECT \"teachers\".\"id\" FROM \"teachers\" WHERE \"teachers\".\"school_id\" = 1)"
```

Which is working as well, but uses a nested query to obtain the teacher ids.

There is yet another way that I see used from time to time:

```rb
school = School.first
teacher_ids = school.teachers.pluck(:id) # only select the teacher ids
students = Student.where(teacher_id: teacher_ids)
```

I'd not recommend to do it this way though. It will fire two queries to get the students and transfer back and forth more data:

- one to get all the teacher ids
- one to get all the students belonging to to those teacher ids

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the clarification on the naming and relationships. I’d just to clarify some other things. Yes, I want to implement a many to many relationship between the teachers and the students. But wouldn’t that mean I’d have to construct a bridge table? Based on my research “through:” is followed by a join table. I don’t quite seem to understand your last code specifically the through: :teachers part. Would you have any guides for this by any chance? The official Rails guide only has the bridge table example.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you want to use the has and belongs to many association, then give it a try first and ask a new question if there are problems. hope this helps.

there is a learning curve for all of this. especially if you are new to all the involved techniques (rails, ruby, DB) but you'll get there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Student.where(teacher: Teacher.where(school: school))
```

Comment: Got it! It works. I think you made a typo there. I changed "students" to Student and it works! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that. No problem

Comment: @Soundwave98 I recommend pascal's approach which is has_many :through it will give you the power to fetch students using school like this: school.students